# Sending $(this) in a callback

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery click event

```
$('#sidebar .nav a span').click(function () {
  var sidebar_nav = $(this);
  $("#main").load("type_change.php?id="+id, successCallback);
```

And then i have the callback to do the binding

```
var successCallback = function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
  //doing all the binding in here
}
```

Is there a way to pass `$(this)` or `sidebar_nav` or to the `successCallback` function so I can do something with it

Comment: ask yourself, what happens when you click on 2nd span before the first load event rises?
i think you need a design reconsideration. cannot propose one because i'm not sure about what you really need. but your error is that you have navigation links that you want to pass to asynchronous event of a single element. the load event may not rise in the exact order you assume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [**`$.proxy`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$("#main").load("type_change.php?id="+id, $.proxy(successCallback, $(this)));
```

This will set `this` inside `successCallback` to whatever you pass as second parameter.

If you want `this` still to refer to `$("#main")`, then you could change the callback to accept one more parameter:

```
var successCallback = function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, target) {
  //doing all the binding in here
}
```

and call it like so:

```
var sidebar_nav = $(this);
$("#main").load("type_change.php?id="+id, function() {
    var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
    args.push(sidebar_nav);
    successCallback.apply(this, args);
});
```

`target` will refer to `sidebar_nav`.

Comment: Good point on retaining the `#main` element as `this`. That may be what OP intended. +1

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a function, and use `.apply()` to invoke your function:

```
$('#sidebar .nav a span').click(function () {
  var sidebar_nav = this;
  $("#main").load("type_change.php?id="+id, function() {
       successCallback.apply( sidebar_nav, arguments );
   });
```

Now, `this` in your callback will be the element that was clicked, and the other arguments to the `load()` callback will be passed along as well.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `successCallback.apply(sidebar_nav,arguments)` be more appropriate? `this` in your example is calling back `#main`.

Comment: @Buzzedword: Yes, I already caught that. I was focused on the wrong element. Thanks for the heads-up though. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to generate the callback function and provide `this` as an argument to the generator:

```
var genSuccessCallback = function (element) {
  return function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    // use "element" here
  }
}

$("#main").load("type_change.php?id="+id, genSuccessCallback(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you couldn't use an anonymous function in the callback? For instance:

```
$('#sidebar .nav a span').click(function () {
    var sidebar_nav = $(this);
    main.load("/shop_pos/includes/business_type_change.php?industry_category_id="+industry_category_id+"&business_type_id="+business_type_id+"&class_id="+class_id+"&quantity="+quantity, '', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Function can read sidebar_nav here
        if (textStatus == 'success') {
            // Do stuff here, including that $.post that you might want to do.
        }
    });
```